# Google Rich Text Editor Demo not running on localhost

Tags: javascript, editor, rich-text-editor, demo

I'm trying to run the google editor demo on my local machine to see if I can use it in my project.

https://google.github.io/closure-library/source/closure/goog/demos/editor/editor.html
[image]

I've downloaded the latest stable source code:
https://github.com/google/closure-library/releases

Unzipped the source code on my local machine and went to folder closure\goog\demos\editor
And Opened editor.html without changing any source code.

I get an incomplete editor with no buttons and not working as per the demo on github, maybe I'm missing something.

[image: google editor]

Answer (score 1):

This is a `node.js` project and not a single HTML page.

You should follow the [official tutorial](https://github.com/google/closure-library#using-with-nodejs) to use it.